# AchartEngine chart value colors

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to set the chart values color to a different from the line color.  I cannot seem to find in the current api a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Nobody knows if it is possible to change the colors on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed chart values labels have the same color as the chart (line, bar,...) itself. You can control that by changing the color in the renderer.

Comment: Yes I have seen where the color for the renderer can be set with setcolor but is there a way for the label to have a different color from the chart(line, bar,...).  Also in addition is there a way to set the font size of the label?

Comment: Label color no, font size: renderer.setChartValuesTextSize();